# javascript to find images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the images on a page using the following:

```
var Images = jQuery('img[src$=".jpg"], img[src$=".jpeg"]');
```

However, it does not find something that does not have the jpg extention like http://s1.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20121204&t=2&i=681048372&w=460&fh=&fw=&ll=&pl=&r=CBRE8AM1T7A00

How can i find such images..

Comment: Why not just `'img[src]'` (or `'img'`)?  Do you really care if it's a jpg or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to filter on only .jpg images, then simply looking for image elements should suffice:

```
var $images = $('img');
```

Or if you only want images with a source, then:

```
var $images = $('img[src]');
```

Comment: Though i would have preferred to exclude gifs(animated, spacer etc), this is good for me now.. so, agree with all answers, which are similar anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $images = $('img[src]');
```

Selects all images that have a source..